# how to get time execution of a program in linux terminal separately

Tags: linux, bash, time, terminal, linux-mint

I want to get time of execution of a program in my terminal. I know that I should use this command:

```
time chmod +x ~/example
```

but the output is this:

```
real    0m0.088s
user    0m0.057s
sys     0m0.030s
```

But I want to access each one separately. for example just `real`. how can I get that?

Comment: BTW, timing a `chmod` command is not very significant and not very useful (e.g. because of the [page cache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_cache)....) In general, you should benchmark *several times* an execution which lasts at least half a second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `-f` to format the `time` command:

```
$ /usr/bin/time -f "\t%E Elapsed Real Time" touch a
    0:00.00 Elapsed Real Time
```

The geek stuff has a very broad documentation on this topic: 
[12 UNIX / Linux Time Command Output Format Option Examples](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/10/time-command-format/).

It is also funny that calling it with `time` alone did not work to me, I have to use the full path.

Comment: Yep, it needs /usr/bin/time

Comment: On OSX I am getting `/usr/bin/time: illegal option -- f` It is probably gnu version of `time`

Comment: It's great how nothing is ever properly standardized, isn't it. >.<

Comment: Haha indeed, I recently read something like "it is great to have many standards to chose from" :D

Comment: @anubhava it is gnu, and to be clear for everyone else the time builtin and `usr/bin/time` are two completely separate programs with no relation to each other, other than doing pretty much the same thing. Also in most situations `usr/bin/time` exceeds the `time` builtin

Answer (score 2):

In bash, you can influence the ouput of `time` with the `TIMEFORMAT` variable, by setting

```
TIMEFORMAT=%R    # real
TIMEFORMAT=%U    # user
TIMEFORMAT=%S    # sys
```

before calling it. However, your problems probably don't end there -- capturing the output of `time` is not trivial with bash because it's not a subprocess but a shell builtin. There's an entry in the [bash FAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/032) on the topic. Going from there, I think you ultimately want

```
TIMEFORMAT=%R myvar=$( { time chmod +x ~/example > /dev/null 2>&1; } 2>&1 )
```

Then `$myvar` will be the real running time of the command.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
(time chmod +x ~/example) |& awk '$1=="real"{print $2}'
0m0.003s
```

Comment: Or simply `(time chmod +x ~/example) |& grep '^real'` - which works with `bash`

Comment: `grep` can also be used, `awk` is there to get the actual value in output i.e. `0m0.003s` instead of `real       0m0.003s`